# Can I use JBoss AS 5 or 6 with a Firebird or InterBase SQL server?

Tags: java, firebird, jboss5.x, interbase, jboss6.x

Today I tried to configure a JDBC resource in the JBoss AS 6 RC1, and encountered a field which requires a RAR name. If I have a database with a JDBC driver, do I also need a RAR file for the configuration in JBoss AS?

In GlassFish v3, only the JDBC driver was required for the installation. Or is there a generic (one size fits all) RAR which can be used if no vendor-provided is available?

For **Firebird** I found this:

- FAQ entry [How do I use JayBird with JBoss?](http://www.firebirdsql.org/index.php?op=devel&sub=jdbc&id=faq#7)
- RAR file included in the JayBird JDBC driver download
- firebird-ds.xml included in JBoss docs/examples/jca

For **InterBase** I found:

- no information about JBoss configuration
- no JCA resource adapter file (RAR)
- no datasource example in JBoss

Maybe the JayBird JDBC driver can be used with InterBase. However its development is quite inactive (patch 2.1.6 from 2008, 2.2 development snapshot from 2006)

Comment: A new release of Jaybird is needed only when a new JDBC/JDK version is released. It's a mature and very stable product, hence no need for a rapid bugfix cycle as there are few bugs to fix. Thus the slow release cycle. I do expect a JDK 7 version soonish :)

Answer (score 1):

You have data sources for various connectors i.e various DB Vendors which can be usually found in /docs/examples/jca folder.

Just copy the file related to vendor, give a name for jndi resource, change the credentials,drivers etc and put it in deploy folder. After which the Datasource can be accessed using JNDI

Please make sure to copy related JDBC Drivers to lib folder of deployment or any other configuration you are using [ we can find all, minimum,default configurations in jboss]

If you don't find a datsource example , please copy generic-ds.xml

Comment: in addition to this (the sample ds is there), take the jaybird-xxx.rar from your Jaybird distribution zip (download from the Firebird website) and put that into your server/deploy directory as well.